# Image Not Centering In ScrollView after Zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to centre an imgView inside a scrollView so that when I zoom in, it will remain centred properly (like the photos app).

When the screen first loads, it is centred ok.  When I pinch and start to zoom, the position adjusts itself so the image is no longer centred.  See before and after pinch/zoom photos.
The red is the background color of the scrollview.

[image: Before Zoom]

[image: After Zoom]

Here is the code I am using to create the imgView and Center it within the scroll view.
(MonoTouch, but should translate over to Obj-C easy)

private void LoadPageContent(int page)
        {
            //TODO: Code to put here to load image or whateer you want to display on this panel/page

```
        //Each page will have it's own scrollview for scrolling and zooming that image on the page
        var panelScrollView = new UIScrollView();
        _panels.Add (panelScrollView);

        panelScrollView.CanCancelContentTouches=false;
        panelScrollView.ClipsToBounds = true; 

        panelScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
        panelScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 50.0f;
        panelScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;

        panelScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
        panelScrollView.UserInteractionEnabled=true;
        var ui = new UIImage (_assetImages[page], 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up);

        UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(ui);


        panelScrollView.Frame = new RectangleF(scrollView.Frame.Width * (_numberOfPanels - 1),
                                               0,
                                               _pageWidthPortrait,
                                               scrollView.Frame.Height);


        panelScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        //scale down image to get proper fitted imgview dimensions
        float nPercentW = (panelScrollView.Frame.Width / (float)imgView.Image.Size.Width);
        float nPercentH = (panelScrollView.Frame.Height / (float)imgView.Image.Size.Height);
        float newPercent;
        if (nPercentH >= nPercentW)
        {
            //wider than it is tall
            newPercent = nPercentW;
        }
        else{
            //taller than it is wide..
            newPercent = nPercentH;
        }
        int newWidth1 = Convert.ToInt32(imgView.Image.Size.Width * newPercent);
        int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(imgView.Image.Size.Height * newPercent);

        panelScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { 
            return imgView; 
        };

        imgView.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,newWidth1, newHeight);
        imgView.Center = new PointF(panelScrollView.Frame.Width /2,
                                    (panelScrollView.Frame.Height/2));


  //ScaleToFill and ScaleAspect fit - i used scaleaspectfit and it had the same problem
  //I tried scaletofill but resizing the imgView to fit the proper view dimensions so it is like an aspect fit, but same problem
        imgView.ContentMode=UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;//ScaleAspectFit;
        imgView.UserInteractionEnabled=true;

        panelScrollView.ContentSize = imgView.Image.Size;


        panelScrollView.DidZoom += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

    };

    panelScrollView.AddSubview(imgView);
    scrollView.AddSubview(panelScrollView);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me

```
- (void)centerScrollViewContents {

CGSize boundsSize = ScrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = ImageView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

ImageView.frame = contentsFrame;
```

}

You have to call this method in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Comment: This has no effect for me.  It doesn't work, and the results end up being the same.  I have tried variations of this approach in scrollViewDidZoom and none of them work.  I assure you that the code is being hit though and running.  Just doesn't solve anything.

Comment: are you using panelScrollView or scrollView for centring?? You should use panelScrollView for centering imageView.

Comment: If I set the background colour, it will not show it.  The frame of the image is exactly what you see here.  It's apparent in the code too by looking at imgView.ContentMode=UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill and my calculation that calculates the size of the frame based on the dimensions of the image keeping aspect ratio in mind.

Comment: What do you mean?  I believe it is centering based on panelScrollView (red) isn't it?

Comment: I've gotten it to work.  I had to create a new instance of the point struct in MonoTouch.  I've included the code for MT above as part of your answer.

Comment: Let me retract my answer.  There is a problem now that wasn't there before.  The zooming is "jerky" not smooth like it was before now that I have your adjustment code in place.  Any thoughts on how to correct this.  I noticed the delegate fires multiple times during zoom when really I only need it to fire once the fingers have let go and zooming is finished and then ensure the image is positioned in the center.  Ideas?

Comment: this is working great! thanks! should be marked as the right answer.